# What exactly do probability density functions "do"?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Upon considering this definition:

" A random variable is said to be continuous if and only if:

1. its cumulative distribution function $F_X: \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ is a continuous function.
2. there is a non-negative function $f_X:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ such that $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(t)dt\space\space\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

the function $f_X$ is called the probability density function of the continuous random variable X."

1) I seem to have the idea that the pdf associates infinitesimally small points in in the range of X with probability masses i.e. as we integrate over $R_X$ we pick up all the probability masses of the infinites points in $R_X$ (as X is continuous)

Is this intuition correct?

If not, what is the "correct" intuition for what probability density functions "are" / what they "do"?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It literally describes the *density* of probability at any point, i.e. if you consider a tiny interval $[x,x+\Delta x]$, the probability of the random variable on the interval is approximately $f_X(x)\Delta x$.

Comment: What you are describing is correct in the sense $f$ is riemann integrable hence your description. In a more rigorous sense, this description might not necessarily be true for it to be considered a valid probability distribution since $\delta x$ might not necessarily be properly defined. A more rigorous mathematical description might need to use measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

If a random variable $X$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ is continuous, then its distribution function $F(x):= \mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$ is absolutely continuous, and thus defines a measure $\mu_F$ on $\mathbb R$ with $\mu_F((-\infty,x])=F(x)$ such that $\mu_F\ll\mathsf m$, where $\mathsf m$ is Lebesgue measure. Because both $\mu$ and $\mathsf m$ are $\sigma$-finite, by the Radon-Nikodym theorem there exists a measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ such that for any event $E\in\mathcal F$, $$\mu_F(A) = \int_E f\ d\mathsf m. $$ This function $f$ is called the **density** of $X$.